# Do I need to use a separate database for Laravel Stats Tracker?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

I am setting up [Laravel Stats Tracker](https://github.com/antonioribeiro/tracker) on my website. In its documentation, is says to create a [database connection](https://github.com/antonioribeiro/tracker#create-a-database-connection-for-it-on-your-configdatabasephp) for it like that:

```
'tracker' => [
    'driver'   => '...',
    'host'     => '...',
    'database' => ...,
    ...
],
```

I am wondering, does this mean I have to create a separate database for this plugin? Can I use the same database and just enter the same settings as I have for my default `mysql` database connection? I would rather use one database for everything, including stats. Are there any reasons why I should make a separate database for tracking stats?

Comment: I haven't use it yet. But I think you can use your default connection. No need to create new connection.

Comment: I used the same database, but made `tracker` connection. I copy-pasted all the parameters from my default connection so it connected to the same database using its own connection. It works so far and I haven't run into any problems yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't need another database. You can use the same db.

The package give you the ability to have a different database for stats (even on a different server). The problem with stats is that your database is going to grow very fast. Later on you may also want to query the stats database for statistical reasons (create graphs, reports etc.). So it is very likely that you may want to have your app database and your stats database separated.